# COMException When trying to open specific word files

Tags: c#, ms-office

I would like to open / read my docx documents.  So far everything works but there are some exception's if the file name contains a "_"," ","-" an exception is getting thrown for what ever reason that says:

**Additional information: Sorry, we couldn’t find your file. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?**

What I am doing so far:

```
 string path = "C:/Users/Hans/Rep";
            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.docx"))
            {
                {
                    //Open the doc File
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

                    if (!fileInfo.Name.StartsWith("~$"))
                    {
                        var wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                        var document = wordApplication.Documents.Open(file);
                        //Set paper Size
                        document.PageSetup.PaperSize = WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4;
```

Crash appears when trying to open the file. Is there some specific argument/parameter that has to be set ?!

Comment: Try opening that file by double clicking on them, Once I got the same exception , while investigating I came to know that the file was corrupt.

Comment: @SilverShadow No the are not corrupted, I can open them

Comment: try to open them from another drive

Comment: @SilverShadow it works 100% believe me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this may change depending on what version of Word you are using. I have to supply a lot of parameters to open/close the application and the document. I had to change some things from your partial code. But the code below will open the Word Doc. Hope this helps.

```
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object readOnly = false;
object isVisible = true;
object doNotSaveChanges = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
Object saveChanges = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdPromptToSaveChanges;

public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  string path = "C:/Test";

  Word._Application wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
  foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.docx"))
  {
    {
      //Open the doc File
      FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
      Object fileName = fileInfo.FullName;

      if (!fileInfo.Name.StartsWith("~$"))
      {
        Word._Document document = wordApplication.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing,
                                       ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                       ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                       ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing,
                                       ref missing, ref missing);
        //Set paper Size
        document.PageSetup.PaperSize = WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4;



      }
    }
  }
  document.Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);
  wordApplication.Quit(ref saveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```